# How to Convert a Mercurial Repo into another Repo's Branch

Tags: svn, mercurial, branch

I have a project that was originally in SVN.  I needed to branch, but I accidentally created another SVN Trunk.  Then, later on, the SVN projects were migrated to Mercurial.

I would like to find a way to undo the mistake I made earlier and have only one trunk/repository and one branch, **maintaining the history of both**.  Is this possible through either SVN or Mercurial?

Currently, I have:
REPO A
REPO B

I would like:
REPO A
- BRANCH B

Answer (score 0):

You can omit branches during the svn to mercurial conversion, see an example here:

http://help.fogcreek.com/8200/selectively-converting-svn-branches

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you already converted the repository, you can use history modifying operations to achieve the goal:

1. create the desired branch: `hg branch $BRANCHNAME`
2. rebase the desired trunk onto the newly created branch: `hg rebase -rXXX -d$BRANCHNAME` where XXX denotes the first revision of the brunk to be rebased to the new branch.

For safety, try history operations only on a (new) clone of your current repository.